# Removing silicone from shower but it’s filling a gap!

Tags: bathroom, repair, shower, mold

I was hoping to remove the mouldy silicone from the edge of my shower tray, but once I started to remove it have discovered that it’s actually filling a very large gap between the tray and the tiled wall. I don’t think I can dig it all out - but have started to remove it already. What do I do?[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dig out enough to put in **backer rod** under the new caulking, and apply new caulking. Which is how it should have been done in the first place.

Foam backer rod is available in multiple sizes and is somewhat compressible (so if you have a 1/2" gap, you want something like 5/8" backer rod so it's firmly squeezed in place, and then it supports the caulking on top of it, rather than having a huge amount of caulking filling a huge gap.)